# Existe alguma forma de arrendondar um valor negativo para zero no VisuAlg?

Tags: algoritmo, visualg

Gostaria que fosse exibido sempre `Vida: 0` no último bloco, mesmo que o valor seja negativo, sem fazer essa "Gambiarra" que eu fiz logo abaixo.

Existe alguma função que arredonde `vidaInimigo`, sem que seja necessário criar uma condição adicional: `Se(vidaInimigo <= 0) entao EscrevaL("Vida: 0")`?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por que o inimigo tinha `4` de Vida, recebeu `39` de Dano, e ficou com `-35` de vida.

Queria que fosse exibido a Vida igual a `0`, e não `-35`.

Imagino que exista alguma função que arredonde pra cima.

Segue o código do algoritmo:

```
algoritmo "RPG"
var
   danoCausado, vidaInimigo, baseDanoPlayer: Inteiro
inicio
   baseDanoPlayer <- 50
   vidaInimigo <- 100
   EscrevaL("Vida: ", vidaInimigo)
   Repita
       danoCausado <- randi(baseDanoPlayer)
       vidaInimigo <- vidaInimigo - danoCausado
       EscrevaL(" >>> Dano causado: ", danoCausado)
       Se(vidaInimigo <= 0) entao
           EscrevaL("Vida: 0")
           senao
           EscrevaL("Vida: ", vidaInimigo)
       FimSe
   Ate(vidaInimigo <= 0)
   Se (vidaInimigo <= 0) entao
       EscrevaL("Inimigo abatido!")
   FimSe
fimalgoritmo
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não é dessa pergunta, mas nao deu tempo de eu comentar na que vc deletou: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string - nao é especifico de Java, mas pode ajudar

Comment: Esse é mais especifico http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/displaying-text-using-printf-method

Comment: E o link foi atualizado para double sem casa decimal, aplicando os links acima: https://ideone.com/irUPu3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal substituir isso:

```
Se(vidaInimigo <= 0) entao
    EscrevaL("Vida: 0")
    senao
    EscrevaL("Vida: ", vidaInimigo)
FimSe
```

Por isso:

```
Se(vidaInimigo < 0) entao
    vidaInimigo <- 0
FimSe
EscrevaL("Vida: ", vidaInimigo)
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado.